# 2011 Insignia 2.0 Diesel. Limp mode, with ECL, but no fault codes

Tags: turbocharger, hose, insignia

I recently changed out the turbo hose as it was split. It had not been idling well, wit hthe revs jumping up and down at idle. It threw out a P2282 code, so after a bit of research checked the hose and indeed found 2 large splits in it. Since changing this out the idling issue has stopped, but now the car is in limp mode, and the check engine light is on. Its not throwing out any fault codes though? Can anyone help me out here.

Comment: If the car is in limp mode and the check engine light is on, then there must be a code or several... Are you using a quality code reader? Pe3rhaps go to a garage with a good one and have the codes read there...